# Execute one or all conditions based on input argument

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a shell script where based on the input argument the script should execute certain condition. I want to enhance it to a point where if the input argument is "all" the script should execute all possible conditions mentioned in the script. The pseudo code control flow is shown below. i want help to define the condition where, when input arg is "all" then all conditions must be executed.

**INPUT**

```
./test.sh <arg1>
```

**Algorithm**

```
if ($arg1 == a)
    print " Inside a";
elsif ($arg1 == b)
    print " Inside b";
elsif ($arg1 == "all")
    print " Inside a";
    print " Inside b";
fi
```

**OUTPUT**

command-1:

```
./test.sh a
```

result-1:

```
Inside a
```

command-2:

```
./test.sh b
```

result-2:

```
Inside b
```

command-3:

```
./test.sh all
```

result-3:

```
Inside a
Inside b
```

Comment: So is your question just give some bash code that will do what you want? @Yash

Comment: yes Dorilds....

Answer (score 0):

Alright here's the bash code for what you're asking:

```
arg1=$1
if [ "$arg1" == "a" ]; then
   echo "Inside a"
elif [ "$arg1" == "b" ]; then
   echo "Inside b"
elif [ "$arg1" == "all" ]; then
   echo "Inside a"
   echo "Inside b"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, but consider each `echo` statement as a 15 line code which i dont want to repeat in `elif [ "$arg1" == "all" ]` condition. I want a solution that is scalable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement:

```
case $1 in
    a) echo "Inside a" ;;
    b) echo "Inside b" ;;
  all)
       echo "Inside a"
       echo "Inside b"
       ;;
    *) ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks, but consider each `echo` statement as a 15 line code which i dont want to repeat in third `case` statement. I want a solution that is scalable and easy to maintain.

Comment: You can put those 15 lines in a function and call it in the case block.  Putting 15 lines inside an if block or case block hardly makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution for me is as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x
set +e

arg1=$1

# Function Definition

func_a ()
    {
        echo " Inside a "
    }

func_b ()
    {
        echo " Inside b "
    }

# Invoking functions based on input params

if [ "$arg1" = "a" -o "$arg1" = "all"  ];
then
    func_a
fi

if [ "$arg1" = "b" -o "$arg1" = "all"  ];
then
    func_b
fi

#EOF
```

The result of execution are as under:

```
bash-4.2$ ./test.sh a
 Inside a 

bash-4.2$ ./test.sh b
 Inside b 

bash-4.2$ ./test.sh all
 Inside a 
 Inside b
```

Please not that the way input `"all"` is defined in the if conditions makes this solution scalable and maintainable.